# Brew mysql and ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I have mysql installed:
`mysql  Ver 8.0.27 for macos11.6 on arm64 (Homebrew)`

It stopped working after i did:
`brew services mysql restart`

I didn't do `mysql_secure_installation`, and don't want to do it, to not enter the root password every time. It's on my local machine only.

What should i do? Thanks.